# How to execute an mpiexec command from ansible (ad-doc or playbook)

Tags: python, shell, ansible, mpi, mpi4py

How to run `mpiexec -host node1,node2,node3,node4 python3 hello_mpi.py` from ansible either using script or shell module where hello_mpi.py file resides on the ansible executor (local machine not the server where it is executed). I know you can use script module for a script on your local machine that needs to be executed on the remote server but I don't know how to do it for python scripts that use `mpiexec`.

UPDATE: `ansible master -m script -a "mpi_run.py chdir=/home/pi/cloud executable='mpiexec -host master,node1,node2,node3 python3'"` doesn't through any errors but freezes and drops the ssh connection with the host unreachable mssg.

`/home/pi/cloud` is the NFS directory shared between all the nodes. The script `mpi_run.py` has to be run from that directory so that other nodes can access it.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use the command module being just a single line of code.

Comment: If you are using Open MPI and run as `root`, you will need to `mpiexec --allow-run-as-root ...`

Comment: @Squashman I am trying to run a script that's on my local machine where i am using ansible.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Nice to see you here. I am trying to use a script on my macbook m1 to execute on the remote raspberry pi master using ansible.

Comment: Although I'm almost sure it will break, you can try to set the [executable for `script`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html#parameter-executable) as `executable: mpiexec -host node1,node2,node3,node4 python3`. Meanwhile, the best option here is to copy the script to the target, then execute it with the `command` module and finally remove it.

Comment: @Zeitounator I tried `ansible master -m script -a "mpi_run.py chdir=/home/pi/cloud executable='mpiexec -host master,node1,node2,node3 python3'"` and it doesn't through any errors but hangs and drops the ssh connection with the mssg host unreachable.

Comment: This is why I started my comment with `Although I'm almost sure it will break...`. Now you're off with the "stronger" solution: copy the file and execute it on the target.